# Buffer when testing soda with DCPIP

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, food-chemistry

We are testing a range of sugary drinks (coca cola, orange juice, and chocolate milk) with DCPIP to detect vitamin C. The coca cola has given a false positive and we were wondering if this is due to low pH or if there is a buffer solution to prevent this from happening?

Many thanks!